# Detect configuration errors with FeatureIDE

Tags: emf, model-driven, model-driven-development, software-product-lines

Is there a way to programmaticaly detect validation errors at configuration files, against user defined constraints with FeatureIDE? If it is the case, how should I proceed to detect them and change the validated configuration? I am using AHEAD as feature-oriented language.

Answer (score 0):

FeatureIDE uses a SAT solver to automatically resolve conflicts on a single configuration. At this moment there is no way to get more information about conflicts between configurations.